# Recursively obtaining path to node in binary tree

Tags: python, recursion, binary-tree

I am having issues getting the path to a node in a binary tree.
Specifically, I don't know how to pop elements off of the stack as I return from a stack frame.

```
def getPath(self, target):

    stack = []

    def _getPath(head):
        nonlocal stack
        nonlocal target

        stack.append(head)

        if head.value == target:
            return stack
        if head.left is not None:
            _getPath(head.left)
        if head.right is not None:
            _getPath(head.right)

    _getPath(self.root)

    return stack
```

Currently, the stack will contain all of the elements in the tree.

Comment: Lists have a `pop()` method... did you try that? To pop elements out of it...

Comment: @JeffMercado Yes, I have tried that. The problem is not the method to use. Its how to implement it recursively (ie. where to put it). So far, I've tried just putting pop() at the end, but that just removes all of the elements.

Comment: Because I am having trouble understanding the problem, let me try to rephrase what you're trying to do. `stack` is a list of nodes in the tree that is meant to represent the path to the target node. You are doing a full depth first traversal to find the node. When you visit a node, you add it to the list, but if you return from that node without having found the target, you remove that node from the list, as it is not the correct path to go down. Once you find the target, return all the way up without removing nodes and you will have the path. That sound about right?

Comment: also, what purpose does returning stack from _getPath() serve if it's already a nonlocal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A problem here is: the information of when the target is found has to be propagated back to the called instances of `getPath`. The construction of the stack is kind of a "side effect" of the finding. Therefore I propose you return a boolean value in `getPath`, that is True iff the target was found within the subtree currently investigated. Then we know we have to attach a value to the "stack":

```
def getPath(self, target):

    stack = []

    def _getPath(head):
        nonlocal stack
        nonlocal target
        if head.value == target:
            stack.append(head)
            return True
        for child in (head.left, head.right):
            if child is not None:
                if  _getPath(child):
                    stack.append(head)
                    return True
        return False


    _getPath(self.root)
    return reversed(stack)
```

Comment: sorry, quite a few errors in the first version, now it should work :)

Comment: You could also use the stack as return value, and e.g. return None if nothing was found in a subtree. So you could avoid the nonlocal stack.